# In Excel VBA - How to use <> criteria in SUMIF formula and have formula in the cell

Tags: excel, vba

I just started learning Excel VBA and have success entering formulas into cells until trying to input a SUMIF formula that uses the criteria "<>".  Here is a sample of the code that has an error:

```
Dim myRange As Range
Dim myDataRange As Range
Dim mySum As Range
Dim myReason As Range

Set myRange = Cells.Find("Year").CurrentRegion
Set myDataRange = Intersect(myRange, myRange.Offset(1))
Set mySum = myDataRange.Columns(12)
Set myReason = myDataRange.Columns(14)

ActiveCell.Formula = "=SUMIF(" & myReason.Address(True,True) & ", ""<>" ," & mySum.Address(True,True) & """)"
```

The ultimate result would be to have a formula in the cell =SUMIF(myReason Range, "<>", mySum Range).  It should add up all numbers where there is an empty cell in the myReason range.

I have managed to get the WorksheetFunction.SumIF(myReason, "<>", mySum) to work but it only has the formula result without showing the formula in the cell.

I thought about naming the ranges and then using the names, however, I will be copy / pasting these cells a couple of times into the same worksheet.  It would cause issues with several cells having the same name.

Thank you for any help you can provide!

Comment: `ActiveCell.Formula = "=SUMIF(" & myReason.Address(True,True) & ", ""<>"" ," & mySum.Address(True,True) & ")"`

Comment: @ScottCraner LOL, I thought I had tried that syntax in one of the numerous times I have changed this over the last couple of days but must have been missing something.  Thank you very very much!